# Why I cannot use std::tie to unpack values from vector of pair in range based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std-pair, stdtuple

Can please someone explain why this compilation error.

Error: function template "std::tie" is not a type name
This is working fine.
tie(str1,str2) = pairval;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<pair<string,string>>v ={{"Hello", "Task"}};

    pair<string, string> p = {"Hello", "Task"};

    string str1, str2;

    for(auto & pairval : v)
    {
        tie(str1,str2) = pairval;
        cout<<pairval.first<<" "<<pairval.second<<endl; //working
    }

    for(auto & [str1,str2]: v)
    {
       cout<<str1<<" "<<str2<<endl; //working
    }
    
    for(tie(str1, str2):v) // compilation error : function template "std::tie" is not a type name
    {
           cout<<str1<<" "<<str2<<endl;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::tie` is not a declaration. Basically your code violates C++'s grammar. Also, this is C++17, not C++11 (C++11 doesn't have structured bindings)

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the range-for-loop definition:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

here `range_declaration` needs to be a *declaration*. `std::tie(str1,str2)` is not a declaration. Declaration is something like `int x` or `auto&& y`.

See cppreference for range-for-loop https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations for declarations.